# MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.7.68.60:27017

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server

i am getting this error when i'm trying to connect with mongodb after updating nodemon (I AM USING MONGODB ATLAS)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpsS0.png)

I have try to create a new user and user the user name and password and try to add my current ip address still not working.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.